# how to iterate over object array based on values, not key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I know I can iterate over an object array and check values by utilizing the key. But is there a way to check the key by looking at the value? I use jQuery although I think this is simply a javascript question.

```
var j = [
    {hello : 1},
    {hello : 2},
    {bye : 3}
]


$.each(j, function(i,item){
    if(item.hello==1) alert("hello");
});
```

How do I make the alert dependent on the value being 1, irrespective of what key it is?

Comment: You would to iterate through all the keys to find the value you want and then grab the corresponding key.  The data is not indexed by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var j = [
    {hello : 1},
    {hello : 2},
    {bye : 3}
];
$.each(j, function(i, item){;
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
      if (value === 1) {
        alert("it said hello")
      }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to iterate through each key in the array, like this:

```
$.each(j, function(i,item){
    for (var key in item) {
         if (item[key]==1) {
             alert("it said hello");
         }
    }
});
```

But why not store it in another format, if that's how you'd like to use it? ie,

```
var j = [
    [hello, 1],
    [hello, 2],
    [bye, 3]
]
```

Comment: yup. if I knew my data would never change structure i'd do it array-style, but it's not extensible that way. I'm keeping all data in objects so I can store anything I want.

Answer (score 1):

There's the for-of loop proposed in ECMAScript 6.

```
for (item of j){
    if(item.hello==1){
         alert("it said hello");
    }
}
```

This feature appeared in Firefox 31 and it is shipped with Chrome 38. IE doesn't implement it. Don't know about other browsers.

Comment: I like it. But alas, dodgy support atm, so gonna have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

For expample:

```
var j = [ {hello : 1}, {hello : 2}, {bye : 3} ];
for (var i in j)
{
    for  (var s in j[i])
    {
        if (j[i][s] == 1)
        {
            alert("it said hello");
        }
    }
}
```